# How is the $@ array different from regular array

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I wrote a function to check whether argument(s) was passed to script, so I had to create an alias variable for `$@` because inside function that would be function's arguments.
Here's the code:

```sh
script_args=$@

is_arg_passed() {
  local passed=false

  for passed_arg in ${script_args}; do
    for arg in "$@"; do
      if [[ "${passed_arg}" == "${arg}" ]]; then
        passed=true
        break
      fi
    done

    [[ "${passed}" == true ]] && break
  done

  echo "${passed}"
}
```

Though I definitely would like to learn how it can be implemented shorter, that's not the topic of my question (though some advice would be appreciated ;]).

My question is related to the `for passed_arg in ${script_args}; do` line:

Why does it not work when `script_args` expanded within string i.e. `"${script_args}"`, when `"${@}"` or `"$@"` does.
Only `${script_args}` works.

So how is `$@` different from the regular array (like `(a b c)`), and how is `script_args` different from `$@`?
What is the catch?

Comment: It's not an array at all, and neither is `script_args`.

Comment: @chepner I only know bash one and a half day, so I don't know much

Comment: @rowboat the intention was to check if any of the given args present. Thanks for the information, yeah I already realised that it's better to `return` status from function. Wow, zsh way is pretty elegant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're not different based on how you compare them because an array much like the positional parameters is expanded with a quote: `"${script_args[@]}"`

Also you're storing the arguments wrong. With `script_args=$@` you store a string value to `script_args`. The value is a merged form of the values of `$@` with the space used as a conjunctor.

To store them as an array, use `script_name=("$@")`. Read the [Arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) section of the Bash manual to know more about it.

Comment: Thank you! Very useful information. I have another question: what is the role of quotes in `script_args=("$@")`? Will the result be any different without quotes in this case? Also when I tried `script_args=("$@ x y z")` out of interest I got `"a" "b" "c x y z"`. How it works? that quoting stuff is so confusing for a newcomer like me...

Comment: @felps321 Not quoting it results to Word Splitting and Filename Expansion which isn't what you want. Both are topics in the manual. You can look those up.

Comment: I mean, isn't `$@` already word-splitted? (sorry for being meticulous)

Comment: Yes it gets "splitted" based on its actual contents but they stay the way they are, unlike actual word splitting where an element like `"abc xyz"` becomes `"abc"` and `"xyz"`.  Try `set -- "abc xyz" "123"; a=("$@"); b=($@); declare -p a; declare -p b`. The output would show you the difference.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and answering me. I wish you the best

Answer (score 2):

`$@` is not an array, though it is array-like.

The assignment `script_args=$@` simply creates a regular parameter whose value is the contents of `$@` concatenated with a space. If you really want an *array* with the same contents, use

```
script_args=( "$@" )   # The quotes are critical!

is_arg_passed() {
  local passed=false

  for passed_arg in "${script_args[@]}"; do  # So are these quotes!
    for arg in "$@"; do
      if [[ "${passed_arg}" == "${arg}" ]]; then
        passed=true
        break
      fi
    done

    [[ "${passed}" == true ]] && break
  done

  echo "${passed}"
}
```

This kind of containment check can also be done using an associative array (as long as the arguments are not empty strings).

```
declare -A script_args
for arg; do
  # The value doesn't matter; we'll only be checking
  # if the key exists.
  script_args["$arg"]=
done

is_arg_passed() {
  for arg; do
    if ! [[ -v "script_args[$arg]" ]]; then
      echo false
      return 1
    fi
  done
  echo true
  return 0
}
```

Comment: thank you! then I have two more questions: what's role of quoting in this case (I'm absolute noob in shellscripting)? and second, what is this for loop? Does it use `$@` automatically?

Comment: Yes, `for x;` is equivalent to `for x in "$@"`. The quotes ensure that each element produced by the expansion is a complete value from the arguments; unquoted, space-containing elements will themselves be treated as multiple elements.

Comment: Oops. The `${...}` was a brain fart; I don't know that I never tried using an empty string as an array key.